# How to use a separate model class for validation in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure on how to implement this, I have a MovieController.cs in the Controllers folder and a MovieCreateViewModel.cs in the Models folder. I need to add validation for the create, edit and delete views.

MovieDetailsViewModel.cs

```
public class MovieDetailsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 }
```

then I have MovieController.cs

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{

    Connect connection;
    MovieCreateViewModel movie;
    MovieDetailsViewModel id;

    public MovieController()
    {
        this.connection = new Connect();
        this.movie = new MovieCreateViewModel();
        this.id = new MovieDetailsViewMode();
    } 

    public ActionResult Edit(MovieDetailsViewModel id)
    {
        movie = this.connection.MovieContext.Where(m => m.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();  **//I get an error here**
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MovieCreateViewModel movieedit)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this.connection.MovieContext.AddObject(movieedit);
                this.connection.MovieContext.Context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            return View(movieedit);
        }
    }
```

for the httpPost I made the type `MovieDetailsViewModel id` in the parameter list
Where do I go from here please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you go through the MVC tutorial ?http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: Please see the code above I replaced it with the validation for Edit seeing that this is where I get the error with the lambda expression. Thanks

Comment: First of all, In your Edit (GET) method, I can see that you specified the viewmodel as the parameter itself instead of int. Is it a typo ? If not, note that you don't have to specify the entire Viewmodel, it can be just public ActionResult Edit(int id). Put a breakpoint and see what you are getting as id. And you dont have to filter by where and then by singleordefault. singleordefault will do the job..

Comment: ooo ok I did not know that I somehow thought I need to make the type of type MovieDetailsViewModel where I only have the id property?

Comment: i have added the code below, what you get from context is the model, convert that into viewmodel, where you can add data annotations as well for validation and pass it to view. On the post method, you can convert the viewmodel back to model and save changes. And a cleaner thing would be to write functions in the viewmodel itself like LoadModel which will load the model to the VM properties and RetrieveModel which would convert back the VM into a model so that the controller is not polluted with the conversion code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better practice would be use seperate model and viewmodel. Convert your model to viewmodel and then pass it to view

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     var movie = this.connection.MovieContext.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
     var vm = new MovieCreateViewModel{ Id = movie.Id};
     return View(vm);
}

//
// POST: /Movie/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MovieCreateViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var movie = new Movie{Id = vm.Id};
            this.connection.MovieContext.Attach(movie);
            this.connection.MovieContext.Context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        return View(movieedit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation will now be performed on your model instance, to check it, you do:

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

In the controller method prior to the save operation. As long as the input names on the view correspond with your model class's property names, binding and validation will be performed implicitly prior to your action method being executed. To show your validation messages in your view, add a  Html.ValidationMessage() to the top of the view. Hope this helps. By the way its well worth checking out [Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which provides conditional validation attributes and some other good stuff.